# Haskell Noob In Need of Assistance

Tags: bash, haskell

This is a bit long, so bear with me!

I'm having a bit of trouble working with a Haskell program, that I have to use as part of a uni project. For reference, it's [Casper](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/gavin.lowe/Security/Casper/).

So, you're supposed to execute a script, which is actually a Bash script to invoke Hugs interpreter like this:

```
exec $HUGSBIN/hugs $HUGSARGS +p"Casper> " $FILES
```

Where $FILES points to a Main.lhs file.

After this, I need to invoke a function "compile" with a path to a file, in the interpreter.

I need to perform the above in a scripted manner. I need this automated because I'm writing a program that will call on Casper in the background.

So I compiled the .lhs file. Now I want to execute the "compile" function but I have no idea how this is done. I try:

```
./Main compile <a path>
```

from the command line but it returns me an error about a file "test" not found. Upon investigation, I see these lines in the Main.lhs file:

```
>main :: String -> IO()
>main = compile "test"

>compile :: String -> IO()
>compile s = catch (compile0 False s) handler

[...snipped]
```

The 2nd line solves this question. Now my question is, how do I invoke the "compile" function and pass a path to it after I have compiled main.lhs? From the interpreter, I just type "compile " and it works, but I can't get the same to work after compiling the main.lhs and executing from the command line? Any ideas why? Is there any way I can script Hugs if all else fails?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may access the command-line arguments passed to a Haskell program via `getArgs`. For example, it sounds like you want a main function that does something like this:

```
>main = do
>    args <- getArgs
>    case args of
>        [] -> putStrLn "What file did you want me to compile?"
>        [filename] -> compile filename
>        _ -> putStrLn "I only compile one file at a time."
```

Modify to taste.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! Can you explain what your code does? I kind of get it except am not familiar with Haskell. I especially want to know what the last 3 lines mean. I assume: Empty string, print the message. If an arg is provided, call it "filename" and call "compile filename". If more than one args, tell the last message?

Comment: @Inf.S: This is basically correct. `getArgs` is an action that gives a list of the command line arguments. The first line binds this list to the name `args`. A list can have a variable number of elements, so the last lines do a pattern match on the list to find out how to proceed. If `args` matches the empty list, print message. If args matches a list with a single element, call that element `filename` and proceed to compile that file. The last line uses `_` to match. This is a special case match that always succeeds, but the rule for pattern matching is try to match from top to bottom (cont.)

Comment: @Inf.S: (cont'ed) so if that match is ever made, it means the first two lines didn't match, so it must be a list of two or more elements. If the last line had been the first after `case args of`, then the program would only ever print `"I only compile one file at a time"`, no matter how many arguments it got.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `main` with

```
 main = getArgs >>= \(arg1:_) -> compile arg1
```

This will pass the first command line argument (`arg1`) to `compile` instead of "test", and ignore the rest (`_`). You may need to add

```
 import System
```

or

```
import System.Environment
```

I can't remember what is needed in hugs  for this.

Comment: I get this: Main.lhs:31:9: Not in scope: `getArgs'. Ideas?]

Comment: It was ">import System.Environment". I used Daniel Wagner's code because it was clearer to me. But yours works too! Thanks!